# C#: Events & Thread Safe GUI Updates

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, event-handling

I am in the process of writing an application that communicates with several devices through GPIB commands, running a test on some equipment. I've set up a class, TestProcedure, which will start a new thread, and run the testing. Throughout testing, I've set up several custom events to send information back to the GUI. Here is an example of a simple event:

```
    public event InformationEventHandler<string> TestInfoEvent;
    /// <summary>
    /// Event raised when information should be passed back to the main testing form.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="s">Information to send back to form.</param>
    private void OnInfo(string s)
    {
        if (TestInfoEvent != null)
            TestInfoEvent(this, s);
    }
```

Which would be handled through the GUI, updating a text box like this:

```
TheTestProcedure.TestInfoEvent += new TestProcedure.InformationEventHandler<string> 
                                 (InfoOccurred);
....
private void InfoOccurred(Object sender, string s)
{
    this.textBox1.Text = s + Environment.NewLine + this.textBox1.Text;
    if (this.textBox1.Text.Length > 10000)
        this.textBox1.Text = this.textBox1.Text.Remove(1000);
}
```

This event handling seems to be working fine. I haven't received any cross threading issues, and overall it's been working as expected. However, on another form I just added a similar event handler, which throws a cross-thread exception. The event fires, sending a simple class with a bit of information that I display in an InputTextBox (A custom ComponentOne control). The particular control does not have a .Invoke method, so I'm looking for alternative solutions to access it asynchronously.

So my question is, are event handlers safe to access controls on a form? If not, how do event handlers fire, and could somebody help educate me, or provide some linked information, as to how an event handler communicates with form controls? Do I need to lock the event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controls on the UI thread may only be accessed from the UI thread - any access from other threads is bound to cause issues. You need to use `InvokeRequired` and `BeginInvoke()` to marshal an event to the right thread if it's not already there.

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527947/invoke-required)

Comment: I should add an invoke to the event itself? Will this work in the same was as say invoking a text box?
Edit: Sorry, just saw your example I'll take a look

Comment: You'd check for `InvokeRequired` first inside your event handler function and if it returns `true`, you need to marshal the call to the UI thread using `BeginInvoke()`. If the return value is `false` you're already on the UI thread so you can safely access the control directly (e.g. `txtName.Text = ...;` is valid then. If you're on the wrong thread, it may fail.)

Comment: I fixed the answer to refer to `BeginInvoke()` since you'll likely need that, not `Control.Invoke()`.

Comment: I just tested, and it's working perfectly. Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to create a delegate callback and `Invoke()` execute that after testing the `InvokeRequired` property.  The following code will handle the addition in a thread safe manner.

```
TheTestProcedure.TestInfoEvent += new TestProcedure.InformationEventHandler<string> 
                             (InfoOccurred);

private void InfoOccurred(Object sender, string s)
{
    LogMessage(s);
}

delegate void LogMessageCallback(string text);

void LogMessage(String message)
{
    if (this.textBox1.InvokeRequired)
        this.Invoke(new LogMessageCallback(LogMessage), message);
    else
    {
        this.textBox1.Text = s + Environment.NewLine + this.textBox1.Text;
        if (this.textBox1.Text.Length > 10000)
            this.textBox1.Text = this.textBox1.Text.Remove(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is "Log"? It should be `this.InvokeRequired`.