# Windows Service: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, service, timer

Trying to convert XML files using XSL and printing the output. However, receiving the following message: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

To set an interval for checking files, added a timer to the OnStart.

```
            if (findPrinter() > 0)
            {
                System.Timers.Timer printNetterCheck = new System.Timers.Timer();
                printNetterCheck.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

                printNetterCheck.Interval = 30000;
                printNetterCheck.Enabled = true;
            }
```

The OnTimedEvent:

```
    private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {            
        getFiles();
    }
```

If any files available, call print:

```
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                try
                {
                    StringWriter xslTransformResult = new StringWriter();
                    XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
                    xslt.Load(xslPath);
                    xslt.Transform(file, null, xslTransformResult);

                    if (print(xslTransformResult) == 1)
                    {
                              //do some things
```

The print function:

```
    private int print(StringWriter transformedXML)
    {
        //assume OK
        int rc = 1;

        try
        {
            StringReader printNetterStreamReader = new StringReader(transformedXML.ToString());
            PrintSystemJobInfo printNetterJob = printer.AddJob("PrintNetterPrint");

            Stream printNetterStream = printNetterJob.JobStream;


            Byte[] printNetterByteBuffer = UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes(printNetterStreamReader.ReadToEnd());

            printNetterStream.Write(printNetterByteBuffer, 0, printNetterByteBuffer.Length);
            printNetterStream.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //return fail
            rc = -1;
            eventLog.WriteEntry("Error printing: " + e.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
        }

        return rc;

    }
```

When calling print I receive the thread error. Found some stuff about Dispatchers etc.. but those are not available when using services.

Comment: Which line does the exception occur?

Comment: It happens within the Print function, the exception is thrown with Error pritning:.

The only thing hapening within print is the following:
                printNetterStream.Write(printNetterByteBuffer, 0, printNetterByteBuffer.Length);
                printNetterStream.Close();

Either of those lines should cause this, I presume.

Comment: Look at the StackTrace and get the line.

Comment: Excuse me for my stubborness :) .. it is happening on line 190. Which is: PrintSystemJobInfo printNetterJob = printer.AddJob("PrintNetterPrint");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [`PrintQueue.AddJob`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms552914.aspx).

The method makes a COM call which requires the application be running in a single apartment (`STA`). The easiest way to fix that is to add `STAThreadAttribute` to `Main` which will force the application to run in a single thread. If you need multithreading in your application then you will need to implement the necessary plumbing to run the `PrintQueue` separately on an `STA` `Thread`.

```
// Create a factory to hold your printer configuration
// So that it can be retrieved on demand
// You might need to move the findPrinter() logic
public class PrintQueueFactory
{
    private static PrintQueue _instance = new PrinterQueue(/* Details */);

    public static PrintQueue PrintQueue { get { return _instance; } }
}

private int print(StringWriter transformedXML)
{
    //assume OK
    int rc = 1;

    try
    {
        var printer = PrintQueueFactory.PrintQueue;
        var staThread = new Thread(() => Print(printer, transformedXML.ToString()));
        staThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        staThread.Start();
        staThread.Join();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //return fail
        rc = -1;
        eventLog.WriteEntry("Error printing: " + e.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
    }

    return rc;

}

private static void Print(PrintQueue printer, string lines)
{
    using(var printNetterJob = printer.AddJob("PrintNetterPrint"))
    using(var printNetterStreamReader = new StringReader(lines))
    using(var printNetterStream = printNetterJob.JobStream)
    {
        Byte[] printNetterByteBuffer = UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes(printNetterStreamReader.ReadToEnd());
        printNetterStream.Write(printNetterByteBuffer, 0, printNetterByteBuffer.Length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe, as you are using a Timer control, it is related with multi-threading, maybe you should check if an Invoke is Required (InvokeRequired) in the Timer.Elapsed event handler.

If so, you should create a delegate to call this function, so it can be executed in the right thread.

[Check this Invoke-Required question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527947/invoke-required)